# Electron Application with plugin modules

Tags: node.js, electron

I am looking to build an application that has cross platform with a plugin architecture. I see that **Electron** is a good fit for kind of requirement, however I am unable to understand how the plugin architecture can be implemented in electron.

Think of this as a tool that will evolve over time with team adding new functionalities over time. I am looking at making this as a plugin and delivered to the app to enable new features (UI + Logic) once the application is deployed.

I am really new to both `NodeJs` and `electron` so this may sound very basic ask, however I have been looking around the net but can't see any explanation on how to address my requirement. Can someone please help me point to the right resources on the net.

Regards
Kiran

Comment: There is probably many possible approach to do that. Here is one: https://github.com/evolvelabs/electron-plugins

Comment: @lenikhilsingh :Please have  look at https://github.com/theia-ide/theia this may be of interest for you

Answer (score 0):

I am using Vue and Vuetify at work. I tried to implement them on electron and I can suggest you to do same thing. There are some plugins that automatically add vue support to your current electron project without any effort. Once you add vue support its like developing a web client but only difference is you have node.js functionalities. After you do that you can make a project structure that you split your modules how ever you want. I may share the project structure that I use in my projects if you want. I can edit my post depending on your questions if you want to go on this way. Cheers!!

Comment: Your structure sounds very interesting and useful! Are you willing to share it? Thank you!

Comment: How do you update core application and how do you update plugins? How do you distinguish between core app and plugin? Can user install/add only plugins he needs at the moment or once he install app, this app has all available plugins?